# DHTMLX - After pagination, Click on Grid redirects to Page 1

Tags: javascript, pagination, grid, dhtmlx

I'm using DHTMLX Pro and rendering the table with these configuration. Pagination works fine. After pagination when I click on any row or any cell in the Grid, it is automatically redirecting to the Page 1.

For example: 
When I'm in page 2, when I click on a grid row in page 2, It goes back to page 1.

**grid.js**

```
var per_page = 50;
var $spinner_el = $("#spinnerDiv");   
feedgrid = new dhtmlXGridObject('grid-region');
feedgrid.setImagePath('../../../../static/styles/vendor/dhtmlx/imgs/');
feedgrid.setSkin("dhx_web");
feedgrid.setHeader(["ID","Name","date"]);                 
feedgrid.setColumnIds("id,name,createdDate");
feedgrid.setColTypes("txt,txt,txt");
feedgrid.enableAutoHeight(true);
feedgrid.enableAutoWidth(true);
feedgrid.setEditable(false);
feedgrid.enablePaging(true, per_page, per_page, "pagingArea", true, "infoArea");
feedgrid.setPagingSkin("toolbar", "dhx_web");
feedgrid.init();
feedgrid.load("/getdata", "js");

feedgrid.entBox.onselectstart = function () {
   return true;
};

feedgrid.attachEvent("onXLS", function () {
   spinUtil.on($spinner_el);
});

feedgrid.attachEvent("onXLE", function () {
  spinUtil.off($spinner_el);
  resizeGrid();
});

feedgrid.attachEvent("onRowInserted", function (rId) {
  feedgrid.adjustColumnSize(0);
  feedgrid.adjustColumnSize(1);
  feedgrid.adjustColumnSize(2);
});

feedgrid.attachEvent("onResizeEnd", function (cInd, cWidth, obj) {
  resizeGrid();
});

feedgrid.attachEvent("onPageChanged", function (ind, fInd, lInd) {
  resizeGrid();
});
```

**html**

```
    <div id='grid-region'></div>
    <div class="loading-image" id="table-ajax-loader"></div>
    <div class="paginate-head">
        <div id="pagingArea"></div>
        &nbsp;
        <div id="infoArea"></div>
    </div>
```

Not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to override `onBeforeSelect` DHTMLX event to disable the redirection to page 1,

```
ingestionGrid.attachEvent("onBeforeSelect", function(new_row,old_row,new_col_index){
    //alert(new_row);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I had the same issue with the pagination of a DHTMLXGrid. I thought it was a bug from the library, but this morning I've discovered the problem.

Surely, if you have some attributes in your data xml nodes like **id** or something similar, **the value of those atributes MUST BE ordered and sequential in each async request you make from the grid**. In other case, the grid gets mad (and the developer too). If you can't order, then remove any attributes from the nodes.

For example:

Imagine I return this xml to the grid from the server side:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<rows pos="0" total_count="40">
   <row id="1">
       <cell>...</cell>
       <cell>...</cell>
        ...
       <cell>...</cell>
   </row>
   <row id="2">
       <cell>...</cell>
       <cell>...</cell>
        ...
       <cell>...</cell>
   </row>
   ...
   <row id="n">
       <cell>...</cell>
       <cell>...</cell>
        ...
       <cell>...</cell>
   </row>
</rows>
```

If in the next async request (pagin) you repeat the same numeration of the id atributte (from 1 to n), when you select a row in the grid, then the grid will return to the first page (the 'onRowSelect' event will fire the 'onBeforePageChanged' event).

The good way is to keep a parameter in the server side that stores the first position of the page and then , using this value to build the xml. you can access this data from javascript using those methods:

```
position_start = (grid.currentPage - 1) * grid.rowsBufferOutSize;
```

and then increments the value in each iteration for the 'id' attribute when building the response xml.

So note the value of the attribute **id** from the previous example (for chunks of 15 results in each request):

first async request :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<rows pos="0" total_count="40">
   <row id="1">
       <cell>...</cell>
       <cell>...</cell>
        ...
       <cell>...</cell>
   </row>
   <row id="2">
       <cell>...</cell>
       <cell>...</cell>
        ...
       <cell>...</cell>
   </row>
   ...
   <row id="15">
       <cell>...</cell>
       <cell>...</cell>
        ...
       <cell>...</cell>
   </row>
</rows>
```

In the next async request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<rows pos="0" total_count="40">
   <row id="16">
       <cell>...</cell>
       <cell>...</cell>
        ...
       <cell>...</cell>
   </row>
   <row id="17">
       <cell>...</cell>
       <cell>...</cell>
        ...
       <cell>...</cell>
   </row>
   ...
   <row id="30">
       <cell>...</cell>
       <cell>...</cell>
        ...
       <cell>...</cell>
   </row>
</rows>
```

Following the end of pagination.

Hope this avoids any headache in advance.

Best regards